# Unable to create Oracle XE HR sample

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I'm completely new to Oracle database and trying to follow steps in the 2 day guide: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tdddg/two-day-developer-intro.html

I downloaded an installed the XE database.  I am trying to install the HR sample:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-CB945E4C-D08A-4B26-A12D-3D6D688467EA

However, the script failed.  I've tried to narrow down the issue.

I logged in using sqlplus:

```
>sqlplus "/as sysdba"
```

and then tried to create a user:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Mar 16 00:05:06 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
SQL>CREATE USER hr identified by password;

ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
```

after this error, I read on another form to try the following:

```
SQL> alter session set container = XEPDB1;

Session altered.
```

after the above command, I can create the user:

```
SQL> create user hr identified by password;

User created.
```

I also a sent the command:

```
SQL>GRANT CREATE SESSION TO hr;

Grant succeeded.
```

But when I try below, I get an error:

```
SQL>connect hr/password

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

Any ideas?  I don't know what I need to do to connect as the `hr` user.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect as follows:

```
sqlplus hr/password@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

Comment: You can use TNS entry in form `sqlplus user/pwd@tns_entry_name` to connect to the database without specifying all the connection information at connect. This requires to have [`tnsnames.ora`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tnsnames-ora-file.html) file at `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` or at `$TNS_ADMIN` path (if the second system variable is set). This is more flexible way to manage the connection (with verbose name in case of network or DB configuration changes), it is strange that it wasn't included into 2Day guide.